# Can't load static image file in angular template

Tags: angularjs

I am making  a profile page and for some reason I can't load a static image on it. 
Here is my **find** function which looks for the image in the path '/uploads/profilePic/image_name.jpg' where this folder is inside my app folder. 
The path is stored but the image doesn't display

```
$scope.find = function(){
        $http.get('/profile/'+$stateParams.username).success(function(user){
            $scope.user = user;
            $scope.user.profileImage = '/uploads/profilePic/'+user.profilePic;
            console.log($scope);
        }).error(function(response){
            $scope.error = response.message;
        });
    };
```

My template

```
<img ng-src="{{profileImage}}" alt="temp" class="img-thumbnail"><hr>
```

Comment: ng-src should be user.profileImage

Answer (score 1):

Change your html to this:

```
<img ng-src="{{user.profileImage}}" alt="temp" class="img-thumbnail"><hr>
```

Your ng-src need to equal:

```
ng-src="{{user.profileImage}}"
```

Also, make sure your image is located where your path is pointing.

Comment: how do we determine the path ? i keep getting http://localhost:3000/uploads/profilePic/default.png 404 (Not Found). My upload folder is in the same directory as the app

Comment: That tells me the value of $scope.user.profilePic is "default.png".  You would have to have an image named default.png located in profilePic directory for this to work.

Comment: I have an image with that name in that directory but it doesn't load

Comment: If that's the case you should be able to just type that image url into your browser and it will pull up.  If it doesn't pull up then your path is wrong.  Angular isn't the problem at this point.

Comment: Is the image a png or jpg?  In your question to reference a jpg image in your initial paragraph.

Comment: the image is a png but I also have jpg images in that folder

Comment: Do they pull up when you type their path in your browser?

Comment: No they do not I can only get the image when its the actual path on my machine like /Users/johnny/git/App/uploads/profilePic/Image

Comment: You have to setup your web server correctly then, that's the problem.  Your angular is correct now.  Once you get your site configured to run properly on your server you will be good to go.